# Target only the first click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code, and I need to target only the first click for one line and normal clicks for the rest.

```
$esCarousel.show().elastislide({
    imageW  : 240,
    onClick : function( $item ) {
        if( anim ) return false;
        anim    = true;
        // only in the FIRST CLICK click show wrapper (expected but don't work)
        _addImageWrapper();
        // on click show image
        _showImage($item);
        // change current
        current = $item.index();
    }
});
```

When i click the item, everything works great, but when I click again I need only the “$_showImage($item);” and not the “_addImageWrapper();”.

Can you help me? I'm really a newbie about js :(

UPDATE:
When I close (close with fadeOut) It won't open again! It must be because the carousel is already been clicked… how can I “reset” the click?

```
$navClose.on('click.rgGallery', function( event ) {
    $('.rg-image-wrapper').fadeOut('2000');
    return false;
});
```

Thanks for the help, I'm learning this (I think :x)!

Comment: regarding elastislide() -- does it matter? We can clearly see the part that should be triggered only for the first click. It doesn't matter if it's nested inside a function called "superwhatchamacallit". Would also be curious about why the downvote. A newbie is asking a question, and the answer will teach him how to track a flag. Not downvote-worthy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could set a variable outside this code:

```
var clickedCarousel = false;

$esCarousel.show().elastislide({
    imageW  : 240,
    onClick : function( $item ) {
        if( anim ) return false;
        anim    = true;
        // only in the FIRST CLICK click show wrapper (expected but don't work)
        if(!clickedCarousel) {
          _addImageWrapper();
          clickedCarousel = true;
        }
        // on click show image
        _showImage($item);
        // change current
        current = $item.index();
    }
});
```

Does this fit your need?

**UPDATE:**
Regarding this update:

UPDATE: When I close (close with fadeOut) It won't open again! It must be because the carousel is already been clicked… how can I “reset” the click?

[fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) takes a callback of this form:

```
obj.fadeOut( [duration] [, callback] )
```

callback can be an inline function or a predefined one, so you could use this (inline):

```
$navClose.on('click.rgGallery', function( event ) {
    $('.rg-image-wrapper').fadeOut(2000,function(){
       clickedCarousel = false; // reset to false after fade out is complete
    });
    return false;
});
```

Does that help?

Comment: Edit provided for the reset query

Comment: When I click again the _addImageWrapper(); don't open. Oh, and thanks for the heads up about fadeOut()!

Comment: I'm reading something about .unbind('click') but can't make it work… maybe I have to go this way, no?

Comment: @edmundojr I don't think it's usable in your case because you're using a plugin, but you should have a look to the `one` method http://api.jquery.com/one/ :)

Comment: @MyStream Thaaank you for flagging tip to handle clicks. +1

Answer (score 2):

Wrap `_addImageWrapper()` in an `if (!this.clicked)` condition, then set `this.clicked = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable to keep track of if it's already been clicked.

```
$(function() {
    var alreadyClicked = false;
}

$esCarousel.show().elastislide({
    imageW  : 240,
    onClick : function( $item ) {
        if( anim ) return false;
        anim    = true;
        if (!alreadyClicked) {
            alreadyClicked = true;
            _addImageWrapper();
        }
        // on click show image
        _showImage($item);
        // change current
        current = $item.index();
    }
});
```